# Metro App WebView for html Hyperlink Navigation to open in browser

Tags: windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml, c#-5.0

When clicking on hyperlinks in html hosted by `WebView`, the page opens within the `WebView`. I believe, that Microsoft will fail the applications certification if you allow this.

As such, how do I get the `WebView` to detect navigation within itself and then launch the url in a browser?

Comment: You can add a JavaScript which tweaks all the hyperlink by setting `target = '_blank'`. Call that javascript after webview is loaded.

Comment: How do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to **[Xyroid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1230188/xyroid)** for the tip. This is what I ended up doing:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Regex pattern for getting href links.
        /// </summary>
        private static readonly Regex HrefRegex = new Regex("href=\"([^\"]*)\"", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        // Append target="_blank" to all hrefs
        html = HrefRegex.Replace(html, new MatchEvaluator(HrefReplace));

        /// <summary>
        /// Replaces the contents of href with href and target.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="match">The match.</param>
        /// <returns>The href with target.</returns>
        private static string HrefReplace(Match match)
        {
            return string.Format("{0} target=\"_blank\"", match.Value);
        }
```